# How to accumulate specific index of duplicates in an array whilst using the set method in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, set

I have an array of arrays that is populated by users clicking addToCart.  I want to consolidate the cart list displayed to the user so that entries of the same ordered scent and size appear once with an accumulated quantity.  I am removing any duplicates with the Set method however I am losing the accumulated quantity.

````
        const cart = this.props.order;
        
        const set = new Set(cart.map(JSON.stringify));
        const order = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);
        return (
            <div id="checkoutWrapper">
                <div id="checkout">
                    {order.map((entry,i) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={i} className="orderWrapper">
                                <div>{entry[0]}</div>
                                <div>{entry[1]}</div>
                                <div>{entry[2]}</div>
                                <div>{entry[3]}</div>
                            </div>

                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }``` 
    ```addToCart(orderedScent, size, quantity, price) {
           this.setState(prevState => ({
               cart: [...prevState.cart, [ orderedScent, size, quantity, price ]]
        }))
    }```
How can I consolidate this array of arrays whilst accumulating the quantity?
````

Answer (score 0):

You could get the quantity this way.

Keep the stringified cart, and the stringified array.

```
const sCart = cart.map(JSON.stringify);
const set = new Set(sCart);
const sArray = Array.from(set);
const order = sArray.map(JSON.parse);
```

Then in your map, you can filter it. And the length is gonna be the quatity.

```
{order.map((entry,i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i} className="orderWrapper">
      <div>{entry[0]}</div>
      <div>{entry[1]}</div>
      <div>{entry[2]}</div>
      <div>{entry[3]}</div>

      <div>{"Quantity: " + sCart.filter(str => str === sArray[i]).length}</div>
    </div>
  )
})}
```